Why cant I use a reference to class object within its constructor when passing to another object
game.h
class Game {
public:
    Game();
    int name = 1;
}

game.cpp
#include "game.h"

Game::Game() : player(this),
{
...
}

When instantiating the Game class, I pass a pointer reference of this class to player.
When instantiating player I want to get the integer name.
However I cannot access game pointer due to it being an incomplete type.
Why can't I access it?
IGameActor.h
class Game; // Forward declaration of Game class

class IGameActor {
protected:
    Game* game; // Pointer to the Game object

public:
    virtual ~IGameActor() {}  
    IGameActor(Game* gamePtr) : game(gamePtr) {}
    IGameActor() : game(nullptr) {}

    virtual void update() = 0;

player.h
#include "IGameActor.h"

class Player : public IGameActor {  
public:
    Player(Game* game);
    void update() override;
}

player.cpp
Player::Player(Game* game) : IGameActor(game) { ... }

void Player::update() {
    std::cout << game->name;
}

./build.sh
src/entities/player.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void Player::update()’:
src/entities/player.cpp:54:22: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class Game’
   54 |     std::cout << game->name;
      |                      ^~
In file included from include/entities/player.h:5,
                 from src/entities/player.cpp:1:
include/entities/IGameActor.h:7:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class Game’
    7 | class Game; // Forward declaration of Game class
      |       ^~~~
Compilation failed.

File Structure:

├── game.cpp
├── game.h
├── include
│   ├── entities
│   │   ├── IGameActor.h
│   │   └── player.h
├── main.cpp
└── src
    ├── entities
    │   └── player.cpp


Did you #include "game.h" in player.cpp?

We need a [mcve]. Also refer to a good c++ book

Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste all text as text into your questions.

surely including game.h would cause circular dependency issues?

You should never #include .cpp files anywhere, so there cannot be a circle with a .cpp file. Compiler has to see the definition of Game class to know if it has a member called name and what is its type.

if I include "game.h" in player.cpp then it says no directory exists: src/entities/player.cpp:6:10: fatal error: game.h: No such file or directory
6 | #include "game.h"
|          ^~~~~~~~

Is game.h in a subdirectory? You need to specify either the full relative path to the header file, the full absolute path, or use compiler-settings to tell the preprocessor to also search the directory where the file is located.

What is tileMap?  A [mcve] would be most helpful.  When I modify this sparse code so it compiles, I'm not seeing any problem.  I probably fixed the bug, or the bug is in the code not provided.

The file structure is really bad btw.

In player.cpp you need to include "../../game.h".

You need to include game.h in player.cpp. When doing that figure out the relative path.

Game is at the top of the directory. And tilemap is irrelevant here so i got rid of it. I just can't access the passed pointer. specifying the full relative path neither works.

@user12002570 I am very new to C.

ok passing the entire path /home/____/Desktop/Projects/Game Dev/C++/2D-Terrain-Generation/game.h into player.cpp did work

Why won't relative path work? Which is just #include "game.h"?

Could you elaborate why the file structure is bad please @user12002570

@TaylorThreader Because it doesn't make sense as it doesn't follow any pattern.

What is something better that you would think makes more sense? @user12002570

@TaylorThreader Your header files are missing #include guards.

It's common to have .cpp files in a src folder, and it's also common to have .h files in an include folder. However this would also apply to game.cpp, game.h, and main.cpp, while these 3 files are outside of those folders. That makes this actual organization uncommon. Then come the hypothetical source code lines shown, like void Player::update() in code, but void Player::update(float) in the error message, or the Game::Game() : player(this) constructor with no player field indicated in the class. These are all small thing, but make the post as whole harder to follow.

@TaylorThreader What's a good directory structure for larger C++ projects

When you include using e.g. #include "game.h", the preprocess will first look in the same directory as the source file it's processing. Since there isn't a game.h file in that directory, it will then search the standard include directories. And the file isn't there either, so you get an error.

Also please see What is the difference between #include  and #include "filename"?

Thank you all very much for helping me and the advice, I appreciate it

Two potential issues with this code that I see:

You should include game.h in your player.cpp. It's fine to only forward declare it inside player.h since you're not accessing it's members there. However in your source file you're accessing Game's members so it must be included here.

Your game.h looks incomplete since in Game constructor you refer to "player" member, but I don't see it declared for Game class. At the moment it only has one member, int name. Assuming it's actually there, a potential problem is order of declaration: class members are initialized in order of declaration. So if you initialize player(this) and inside that you need to access int name, you must make sure name is declared before player is. In other words, it's safe to pass this pointer to members in initializer list, as long as you only try to then access members already initialized by this time.


Example:
class Game
{
...
int name = 1;
Player player;
}
would be fine, however:
class Game
{
...
Player player;
int name = 1;
}
would be a mistake, since player would try to initialize before name is initialized
